# How to enforce that 0 not equal to 00 or 000 Python 3.8.5

Tags: python-3.8, zero

----------------------------------------/

i = 0

x = 00

list1 = [(3000,2,1), (9000,0,8), (4,5,6, 000)]

a = (len(list1))

while (True):

```
if (x in list1[i]):

    print ( list1[i])
```

-------------------------------------------------/

This will print: (9000, 0, 8) and (4, 5, 6, 0). This is false result-- How to enforce digit-count or other workaround to avoid this.

Pycharm 2020.2

Comment: `001` and `1` are the same number. If leading-zeroes are important for you, you want strings, not numbers.

Comment: i.e. 0000 int8_t while 00000000 is int16_t. And 00 vector in 2d matrix while 000 vector in 3d matrix.

Answer (score 0):

00 and 000 are the exact same as 0, just as 001 and is the same as 1 (I should mention this is in math, not python).
You'd need to use strings to keep the leading zeros.

This'll work:

```
i = 2
x = "000"

list1 = [("3000", "2", "1"), ("9000", "0", "8"), ("4", "5", "6", "000")]

if x in list1[i]:
    print(list1[i])
```